# Recreating jQuery UI's "Selectable" Interaction in CSS3

Tags: jquery-ui, css

Is there a way to use CSS3 to recreate the behavior of jQuery UI's Selectable interaction, specifically in a grid setup, as [seen here](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be achieved by using a radio buttons `:checked` selector and the sibling selecter (`+` or alternatively `~`)

You essentially have radio buttons that the user can choose, but hide them, and use `<label>`'s with `for=""` attributes.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2vmtX/1/)

This doesn't let you drag or control click to select multiple boxes however, you would need javascript (and checkboxes rather than radio buttons) for that